# Как можно изменить стиль полосы прокрутки у QScrollArea

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Как можно изменить цвет/стиль у полосы прокрутки в QScrollArea?

Comment: Что будем прокручивать? Публикуйте код.

Comment: я думаю это подойдёт в качестве ответа https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007679/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-qlistwidget

Answer (score 1):

**Дальше сам)**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

style = """
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background: #32CC99;
    width: 60px;

    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = QLabel(style)
    w.setFont(QFont('Arial', 50))

    scroll_area = QScrollArea()

    scroll_area.setStyleSheet(style)

    scroll_area.setWidget(w)

    scroll_area.show()

    app.exec()
```

[Qt стиль](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: Я ничего не понял, но это работает.

Comment: Если тебе помог мой ответ то пометь его как правильный.

Comment: Ну, хотелось бы чуть больше объяснений

Comment: Изучай CSS, Qtstyle.

Comment: Ну, я в них ориентируюсь. Просто не могу понять, почему если указать QScrollArea {...}, то код работать не будет. А если не указывать, работает