# Изменение цвета стандартной полосы прокрутки виджета QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qlistwidget, qscrollbar

Как можно изменить цвет стандартной вертикальной полосы прокрутки виджета `QListWidget` в *PyQt5*.

Как это реализовать? Пожалуйста, объясните подробнее, т.к. я новичок.

```
class menuWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, menuDesign.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,mainWin):
        super(menuWin, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint|Qt.WindowTitleHint)
```

На форме присутствует объект `listWidget`. Вот его полосу прокрутки и надо поменять.

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста свой минимальный пример.

Comment: @S. Nick дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То чем вы  дополнили вопрос, даже намеком не похоже на то, что я вас просил.
Минимальный пример - это то, что можно скопировать и запустить!

Если глянуть как наследуется виджет QListWidget 
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QListWidget.html 
то видно, что QScrollBar уже имеется у него внутри.
Вы же в своей программе никак не объявляете 'полосу прокрутки' она как-то сама появляется.

Как уже вам было сказано, что для кастомизации объекта в Qt вы можете использовать stylesheet.
Некоторые примеры использования таблицы стилей Qt посмотрите здесь. 
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Я приведу две таблицы стилей для QScrollBar.
Первая простенькая изменит вертикальную полосу прокрутки, но помните, что 
горизонтальная полоса прокрутки у вас также может появится вдруг.
Вторая - имеет таблицы стилей для вертикальной и горизонтальной полосы прокрутки.
Все можете настроить на свой вкус.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class InputBox(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(InputBox, self).__init__(parent)

        open_message = QtWidgets.QLabel("Enter Value:")
        self.txt     = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        save         = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Save',   clicked=self.accept)
        cancel       = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Cancel', clicked=self.reject)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(open_message, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.txt, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(save, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(cancel, 2, 1)
        self.setFixedSize(self.sizeHint())

    def save(self):
        value = self.txt.text()
        return value


class ListForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, list_of_items, open_text, parent= None):
        super(ListForm, self).__init__()

        open_message    = QtWidgets.QLabel(open_text)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.addItems([str(i) for i in list_of_items])
        add = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add', clicked=self.add_button)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(open_message)
        grid.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        grid.addWidget(add)

    def add_button(self):
        input_box = InputBox()
        input_box.setWindowTitle("InputBox Dialog")
        if input_box.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            val = input_box.save()
            it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(val)
            self.listWidget.addItem(it)
            self.listWidget.scrollToItem(it)



Stylesheet_1 = ("""
QScrollBar:vertical {              
    border: none;
    background: white;
    width: 3px;               
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    min-height: 0px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0 rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    height: 0px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0,
    stop: 0  rgb(32, 47, 130), stop: 0.5 rgb(32, 47, 130),  stop:1 rgb(32, 47, 130));
    height: 0 px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
""")


Stylesheet_2 = ("""
 /* --------------------------------------- QScrollBar  -----------------------------------*/
 QScrollBar:horizontal
 {
     height: 15px;
     margin: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
     border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
     border-radius: 4px;
     background-color: yellow;    
 }

 QScrollBar::handle:horizontal
 {
     background-color: blue;      
     min-width: 5px;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }

 QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal
 {
     margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
     border-image: url(./images/right_arrow_disabled.png);       
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: right;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal
 {
     margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
     border-image: url(./images/left_arrow_disabled.png);        
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: left;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:hover,QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal:on
 {
     border-image: url(./images/right_arrow.png);               
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: right;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }


 QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:hover, QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal:on
 {
     border-image: url(./images/left_arrow.png);               
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: left;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::up-arrow:horizontal, QScrollBar::down-arrow:horizontal
 {
     background: none;
 }


 QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal
 {
     background: none;
 }

 QScrollBar:vertical
 {
     background-color: #2A2929;
     width: 15px;
     margin: 15px 3px 15px 3px;
     border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }

 QScrollBar::handle:vertical
 {
     background-color: red;         
     min-height: 5px;
     border-radius: 4px;
 }

 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
 {
     margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
     border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);        
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
 {
     margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
     border-image: url(./images/down_arrow_disabled.png);       
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on
 {

     border-image: url(./images/up_arrow.png);                 
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }


 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on
 {
     border-image: url(./images/down_arrow.png);                
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
 {
     background: none;
 }


 QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
 {
     background: none;
 }
""")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet_1)                       # <--- или   
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet_2)                        # <--- или 

    window = ListForm(list(range(50)), "List of Values")
    window.setWindowTitle('Demo ListForm')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, сглупил, каюсь. Но спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Для кастомизации любого объекта в Qt вы можете использовать stylesheet.

```
class ScrollBar(QScrollBar):
    def init(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        QScrollBar.init(self, parent, **kwargs)

        self.setStyleSheet("""QScrollBar:vertical {
                    width: 45px;
                    margin: 45px 0 45px 0;
                  }

                  QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
                    min-height: 10px;
                  }

                  QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
                    background: none;
                    height: 45px;
                    subcontrol-position: bottom;
                    subcontrol-origin: margin;
                  }

                  QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
                    background: none;}""")
```

Подробно про это можно прочитать [в документации Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: нет, думаю вы меня не правильно поняли. мне нужно поменять полосу прокрутки именно у listWidget

Comment: Попробуйте задать stylesheet у listWidget и в этом stylesheet прописать цвет scrollbar'a

Comment: сейчас нет возможности , вечером попробую и отпишусь)