# Как поместить QGridLayout в QScrollArea, а QScrollAreа в QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

У меня есть код, который я оставлю ниже. В классе `MyWindow` я создаю два контейнера:

1. Первый контейнер `box` является QHBoxLayout'ом. Второй контейнер `box1` является QGridLayout'ом.
2. В `box1` я помещаю 16 кнопок QPushButton.
3. В `box` я помещаю `box1` и кнопку `button`.

**Мне бы хотелось поместить контейнер `box1` в область с полосой прокрутки, а эту область в `box`.** Как я понял, в PyQt она называется QScrollArea. Нарисовал схему для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я нашел примеры, где QScrollArea используют в качестве главного окна. Это мне не подходит. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать то, что описывалоcь выше?

**Мой код:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(250, 150)
        self.setMaximumSize(250, 150)

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')

        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button3')
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button4')
        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button5')
        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button6')
        self.button7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button7')
        self.button8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button8')
        self.button9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button9')
        self.button10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button10')
        self.button11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button11')
        self.button12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button12')
        self.button13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button13')
        self.button14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button14')
        self.button15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button15')
        self.button16 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button16')

        self.box1.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button3, 2, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button4, 3, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button5, 4, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button6, 5, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button7, 6, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button8, 7, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button9, 8, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button10, 9, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button11, 10, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button12, 11, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button13, 12, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button14, 13, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button15, 14, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button16, 15, 0)

        self.box.addLayout(self.box1)
        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.box)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Установите QtCreator, там можно наиграться с лейаутами до полного дзена

Comment: А QtCreator чем-то отличается от QtDesigner'а?

Comment: то есть, да, QtDesigner. :)

Comment: Лучше замените лейаут с 16-ю кнопками на QListWidget с добавленными в него 16-ю кнопками. Тогда не надо будет стряпать пирожок со скроллареа

Comment: Хорошо. Я попробую создать это в QtDesigner и посмотреть, как это выглядит в коде, спасибо

Comment: Кнопки это намеренное упрощение ситуации:) мне надо сделать более сложную конструкцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно это делается так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(250, 150)
        self.setMaximumSize(250, 150)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button3')
        self.button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button4')
        self.button5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button5')
        self.button6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button6')
        self.button7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button7')
        self.button8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button8')
        self.button9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button9')
        self.button10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button10')
        self.button11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button11')
        self.button12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button12')
        self.button13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button13')
        self.button14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button14')
        self.button15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button15')
        self.button16 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button16')

        self.box1.addWidget(self.button1, 0, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button3, 2, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button4, 3, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button5, 4, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button6, 5, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button7, 6, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button8, 7, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button9, 8, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button10, 9, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button11, 10, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button12, 11, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button13, 12, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button14, 13, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button15, 14, 0)
        self.box1.addWidget(self.button16, 15, 0)

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
#        self.box.addLayout(self.box1)                           # ---
        self.box.addWidget(scrollArea)                           # +++

        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.box)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Динамическое размещение виджетов, вам видимо тоже пригодится.
А то я не представляю размеры вашей программы если вы захотите разместить больше кнопок.

Ваша программа может выглядеть так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(250, 150)
        self.setMaximumSize(250, 150)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(content_widget)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.box1 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(content_widget) 
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')

        for n in range(1, 17):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
                f'Button{n}',
                clicked=lambda ch, n=n: print(f'Button{n}')
            )
            self.box1.addWidget(btn, n-1, 0)

        self.box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
#        self.box.addLayout(self.box1)                           # ---
        self.box.addWidget(scrollArea)                           # +++

        self.box.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.box)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Сейчас буду разбирать ваш код

Comment: @MAXIM045 и еще,  для кастомизации объекта в Qt вы можете использовать stylesheet.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007679/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-qlistwidget

Comment: По поводу вашего обновления. Динамическое размещение означает привязывание конкретных функций к конкретным кнопкам?

Comment: @MAXIM045 нет, это означает, что я заменил `n-ное` кольчество строк - `ДВУМЯ`.

Comment: Понятно, сейчас буду разбираться. По поводу кастомизации, я уже гуглил и наткнулся на ваш ответ, который вы мне скинули. ОЧЕНЬ много непонятных параметров в таблице, буду гуглить их. Кстати, у меня ваш код из того ответа отображается немного иначе, например, горизонтальной полосы прокрутки вообще нет:( Если у вас есть под рукой статья или еще что-то, которая могла бы мне помочь разобраться в характеристиках полос прокрутки - поделитесь ей, пожалуйста